# Removing items from a list while preserving order in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I remove items from a list but keep its original order?
Using `remove()` seems to mess the order up.

Let's say for example a list like this:

```
['book', 'house', 'tree', 'ambulance', 'window', 'Dragonball', 'alfa']
```

How can i remove the words "book" and "tree" without messing up the order?

Comment: It totally doesn't.

Comment: remove doesnt change the order

Comment: do not _iterate_ a list while _removing stuff_ from it ... then you do not get messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably iterating your list while trying to figure out if you need to remove something - you ***never*** iterate a list that you want to insert/remove from - its a recipe for disaster.

Instead create a new list:

```
a = ['book', 'house', 'tree', 'ambulance', 'window', 'Dragonball', 'alfa']
b = [e for e in a if e not in {"book","tree"}]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
['house', 'ambulance', 'window', 'Dragonball', 'alfa']
```

Comment: This was it. If I had posted the full program I have, it might have been easier for experienced people to understand the problem. My bad, I tried to simplify the problem too much! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could just use remove() since it doesn't change list order.

It is often best to just create a new object item like this:

```
item_list = ['book', 'house', 'tree', 'ambulance', 'window', 'Dragonball', 'alfa']
item_list = [e for e in item_list if e not in ('book', 'alfa')]
```

Comment: This is the true. Sorry for the poorly edited question.